# How to use PasswordHasher's VerifyHashedPassword method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I am trying to figure out how to use the VerifyHashedPassword method, and this is what I got so far. How am I supposed to know whether the password has been verified or not?

```
public bool VerifyPassword(string pass)
    {
        PasswordHasher passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher();

        HDA = new HWCDA();

        HWCE = new HWCEntities();

        string userPass = HWCE.AspNetUsers.Where(w => w.UserID == 1).Select(s => s.PasswordHash).FirstOrDefault().ToString();

        bool result = false;

        passwordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(userPass, pass);

        return false;            
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The VerifyHashedPassword method returns a [PasswordVerificationResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.passwordverificationresult(v=vs.108).aspx), which is an enum with possible values of Failed, Success, or SuccessRehashNeeded. You're not evaluating the result of the method at all. What you want is something more like:

```
var result = passwordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(userPass, pass);

return result == PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
```

You can check the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.passwordhasher.verifyhashedpassword(v=vs.108).aspx).

Comment: Awesome, thanks.. Now I got to figure out why I keep getting a fail when verifying, even though the password in pass is correct

Comment: @Chris did you find out why you kept getting fail?

Comment: Bump. Did you ever find out why you get fails?